# Need help on where to call on win checking method for connect 4

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm supposed to make a Connect 4 game that two humans can play. I did most of it, but I don't really know where to call on the checkWin method.

My code is as follows:

```
package arraysex4;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ArraysEx4 {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            int count=0,count2=0,count3,pn=2,x,y;
            String choice;
            int[][]board=new int[9][9];
            boolean isWin=false;
            System.out.println("--Connect 4--\n\nHow to play:\n\nPlayers 1 and 2 alternate as they select a column to drop their chip in.\n\nConnect 4 chips in a row either vertically, horizontally, or diagonally to win.\n");


            while(isWin==false){
                if(pn==2)pn=1;//Changes players' turn
                else pn=2;//Changes players' turn

                display(board,count2);

                System.out.print("Player "+pn+" enter your column choice: ");
                choice=input.nextLine();
                choice=choice.toUpperCase();

                      for(count=0;!"ABCDEFGHI".contains(choice);count++){//Making sure that their column entry is into a valid column.
                          System.out.print("This is not a valid column entry. Please enter a valid column: ");
                          choice=input.nextLine();
                          choice=choice.toUpperCase();
                      }
                      count=8;
                      int ascii=(int)choice.charAt(0)-65;//Converts their letter input to a number in order to coordinate with the columns.

                      for(count2=0;count2<board.length;count2++){//Checks if column is full.
                          if(board[0][ascii]!=0){
                              System.out.print("This column is full. Please enter another colum: ");
                              choice=input.nextLine();
                              choice=choice.toUpperCase();
                              if(count!=8)count++;//Makes sure that array doesn't go out of bounds.
                          }
                          ascii=(int)choice.charAt(0)-65;

                          if(board[count][ascii]>0){//Makes sure that values in column stack.
                              count--;
                          }
                          else{ 
                              board[count][ascii]=pn;                          
                              break;
                          }

                      }

            }




        }
        public static void display(int board[][],int count2){
            for(int count=0;count<board.length;count++){
                for(count2=0;count2<board.length;count2++){
                    System.out.print(board[count][count2]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println(); 

            }
            System.out.println("A B C D E F G H I");
        }


        public static boolean checkWin(int[][] board,int turn,int x, int y){
            boolean win = false;

        // down, right, upright, downright
        int[] row={1,0,-1,1};
        int[] col={0,1, 1,1};
        int count, intR,intC;
        for(int d=0;d<4;d++){ //four possible directions
            count=1;           //reset values to originals for each direction
            intR=x;
            intC=y;
            for(int c=1;c<=3;c++){ //check boundaries with next increment
                if((intR+row[d]>=0 && intR+row[d]<board.length) && (intC+col[d]>=0 && intC+col[d]<board[0].length)){
                    intR+=row[d];   //increment is within the boundaries so move to that spot
                    intC+=col[d];
                    if(board[intR][intC]==turn)count++;  //count a correct spot
                    else break; //incorrect digit found
                } else break; //break stops the loop
            }                //didn't fall within boudaries
            if(count==4){win=true;break;}  //a count of 4 indicates a win

        }
        return win;
        }
    }
```

What I was thinking to do was to add

```
for(int r=0 ; r<board.length;r++){
        for(int c=0 ; c<board[0].length;c++){
            x=ascii;
            y=count;
           if(board[r][c]==pn){
              isWin=checkWin(board,turn,x,y);
   }
```

Inside this else statement inside the for loop.

```
for(count2=0;count2<board.length;count2++){
                      if(board[0][ascii]!=0){
                          System.out.print("This column is full. Please enter another column: ");
                          choice=input.nextLine();
                          choice=choice.toUpperCase();
                          if(count!=8)count++;
                      }
                      ascii=(int)choice.charAt(0)-65;

                      if(board[count][ascii]>0){
                          count--;
                      }
                      else{ 
                          board[count][ascii]=pn;                          
                          break;
                      }

                  }

        }
```

(Because I want it to check for a winner after every choice is entered) However, this did not seem to work.

Please help me figure out where and how to call on it in order to check for a winner.

Thanks

EDIT: So, I have edited a little bit of code (see under), but now only vertical wins are recognized; horizontal, diagonal facing left, and diagonal facing right are still not recognized. I have edited the code below in the aforementioned `else` statement.

```
                          board[count][ascii]=pn;
                          x=count;//Gives x a value in checkWin method
                          y=ascii;//Gives y a value in checkWin method
                          for(int r=0 ; r<board.length;r++){
                              for(int c=0 ; c<board[0].length;c++){
                                  if(board[r][c]==pn){
                                      isWin=checkWin(board,pn,x,y);
                                      break;
                                  }
                              }

                      }
                      break;
                  }
```

EDIT2: I have fixed my problems and have finished my program. If you would like to see my full, finished program; here it is:

```
package arraysex4;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArraysEx4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int count=0,count2=0,count3,pn=2;
        String choice;
        int[][]board=new int[9][9];
        boolean isWin=false;
        System.out.println("--Connect 4--\n\nHow to play:\n\nPlayers 1 and 2 alternate as they select a column to drop their chip in.\n\nConnect 4 chips in a row either vertically, horizontally, or diagonally to win.\n");
        while(!isWin){

            if(pn==2)pn=1;//Changes players' turn
            else pn=2;//Changes players' turn

            display(board,count2);

            System.out.print("Player "+pn+" enter your column choice: ");
            choice=input.nextLine();
            choice=choice.toUpperCase();

                  for(count=0;!"ABCDEFGHI".contains(choice);count++){//Making sure that their column entry is into a valid column.
                      System.out.print("This is not a valid column entry. Please enter a valid column: ");
                      choice=input.nextLine();
                      choice=choice.toUpperCase();
                  }


                  count=8;

                  int ascii=(int)choice.charAt(0)-65;//Converts their letter input to a number in order to coordinate with the columns.   

                  for(count2=0;count2<board.length;count2++){//Checks if column is full.

                      if(board[0][ascii]!=0){
                          System.out.print("This column is full. Please enter another colum: ");
                          choice=input.nextLine();
                          choice=choice.toUpperCase();

                          if(count!=8)count++;//Makes sure that array doesn't go out of bounds.
                      }

                      ascii=(int)choice.charAt(0)-65;

                      if(board[count][ascii]>0){//Makes sure that values in column stack.
                          count--;
                      }

                      else{ 
                          board[count][ascii]=pn;//Adds their input into the array.

                          for(int r=0 ; r<board.length;r++){//Checks the array for values.
                              for(int c=0 ; c<board[0].length;c++){
                                  if(board[r][c]==pn){
                                      isWin=checkWin(board,pn,r,c);
                                      if(isWin)break;
                                  }
                              } 
                              if(isWin)break;
                          }
                          break;
                      }
                  }              
        }

        if(isWin){
            for(count=0;count<board.length;count++){
                for(count2=0;count2<board.length;count2++){
                    System.out.print(board[count][count2]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();   
            }
            System.out.println("A B C D E F G H I");
            System.out.println("Player "+pn+" wins!");
        }



    }
    public static void display(int board[][],int count2){
                for(int count=0;count<board.length;count++){
             for(count2=0;count2<board.length;count2++){
            System.out.print(board[count][count2]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println(); 

        }
                System.out.println("A B C D E F G H I");
    }
    public static boolean checkWin(int[][] board,int pn,int x, int y){
    boolean win = false;

    // down, right, upright, downright
    int[] row={1,0,-1,1};
    int[] col={0,1, 1,1};
    int count, intR,intC;
     for(int d=0;d<4;d++){ //four possible directions
         count=1;           //reset values to originals for each direction
         intR=x;
         intC=y;
         for(int c=1;c<=3;c++){ //check boundaries with next increment
            if((intR+row[d]>=0 && intR+row[d]<board.length) && (intC+col[d]>=0 && intC+col[d]<board[0].length)){
                intR+=row[d];   //increment is within the boundaries so move to that spot
                intC+=col[d];
                if(board[intR][intC]==pn)count++;  //count a correct spot
                else break; //incorrect digit found
            } else break; //break stops the loop
         }                //didn't fall within boudaries
         if(count==4){win=true;break;}  //a count of 4 indicates a win
     }
    return win;
   }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the outer most while loop only happens once per player turn, why not just have it at the top or bottom of that loop?

Comment: @rjustin Because the x and y declarations for the main loop can only be made after the ascii varialbe is declared. Also, I tried putting it at the end of the while loop, and still nothing.